# Equation output to decimal, not scientific notation

Tags: java, bigdecimal

So I have this code:

```
public BigDecimal calculateEWT (BigDecimal amount, boolean vatInclusive, int scale)
{       
    if (isZeroTax())
        return Env.ZERO;

    BigDecimal rateTax = getRate().divide(ONEHUNDRED, 12, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal rateEWT = getcus_tax_EWTRate().divide(ONEHUNDRED, 12, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    rateTax = rateTax.add(Env.ONE);

    BigDecimal ewt = null;
    if (!vatInclusive) {
        BigDecimal base = amount.divide(rateTax, 12, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        ewt = base.multiply(rateEWT);
        System.out.println("EWT VAT not inclusive: " + ewt);
    } else {
        BigDecimal base = amount.multiply (rateTax);
        ewt = base.multiply(rateEWT);
        System.out.println("EWT VAT inclusive: " + ewt);
    }
    BigDecimal finalEWT = ewt.setScale(scale, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    System.out.println("Final EWT: " + finalEWT);
    return finalEWT;
}
```

And
   System.out.println("EWT VAT not inclusive: " + ewt);
prints out "EWT VAT not inclusive: 0E-12," messing up other equations because finalEWT returns 0.00

as example values,
assume amount = 1000, rateTax is 1.12, rateEWT is 0.05

Is there a way to print it out in normal decimal form? I need it to still be in BigDecimal format because I will be inserting the answer to a database.

Comment: You seem to be mixing the actual representation with the output format in your question. Which one do you have problems with?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a method called [`BigDecimal.toPlainString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString%28%29):

> *Returns a string representation of this BigDecimal without an exponent field...*

Comment: I've tried it, but won't it be parsing it to String though? I need it to still be in BigDecimal.

Comment: But you're not changing the instance by calling toPlainString().

Comment: Just change your print statements to `System.out.println("Final EWT: " + finalEWT.toPlainString());`, you're not changing the `BigDecimal`s themselves.

Comment: Problem is I just use System.out as a way of checking values. I'll still be returning the value of finalEWT, and it still returns 0.00.

Comment: That's a different story and has nothing to do with output. If you expect something different from 0.00 then check your calculation. 0 will be 0 no matter how you format it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
System.out.println(String.format("EWT VAT not inclusive: %f", ewt));
```

Formatters (the "%f") are described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dndec). See section "BigDecimal"

EDIT: Answer seems void as the op is actually not asking for another formatting of the output but for checking the calculation. Sorry 'bout that. Please do not downvote. It was a misunderstanding.